# Boolean Algebra Simplification (Exam Prep)

Tags: boolean-logic, discrete-mathematics, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

I am preparing for an exam that I have on monday and the professor said that this would be on the exam for sure. I know the basic theorems of boolean algebra but I cannot quite simplify these 3. If someone could please explain how this would be done without using a truth table or k-map.

[image: boolean]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about discrete math, which is more appropriate at math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

refer your notes. check out the identities you can apply to simplify these expressions. 
eg

1. Y=C(A+A'B')=>C(A+B') using(A+A'B)=A+B
2. Use De Morgan's law
3. if you solve first 2 you can do this one.

[Here](http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Projects/Labview/boolalgebra/) you can refer the basic rules.

Comment: So for the second one after applying DeMorgans I got

A'B' + A' B C' + A C'

but there are no multiples, so what steps would I have to take further?

Comment: @petrov it can be simplified further A'B' + A'BC' + A C'
=>A'(B' + BC') + AC' 
=>A'(B' + C') + AC' (using same rules applied in Q1)
=>A'B' + A'C' + AC' 
=>A'B' + C'(A' + A)
=>A'B' + C'

Answer (score 0):

Well using c++ and letting the computer do the hard work you could do it like this

```
# include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

 int main ()
 {
bool Y1,Y2,A,B,C;
Y1 = true;
Y2 = true;
B = false;
A = false;
C = false;

Y1 = A*C+(!A)*(!B)*(C);

Y2 = (!A)*(!B) + (!A)*(B)*(!C) + !(A+(!C));

if (Y1)
    cout << "First" << "True"<<endl;

if (Y2)
    cout << "Second" << "True"<<endl;

system("Pause");
return 0;

}
```